# How should be defined the field dateIni in model

Tags: angular, angular6

I use a field for a date: `dateIni`.

As I use it with [ng-boostrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), and [DatePicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview), I must set his date with the following format:

```
tournament.dateIni = {year: 2017, month: 8, day: 8}
```

In my model, I defined it as a string, but it is not congruent. How should I define dateIni in my model, with which type ?

Is it mandatory to create another model called Date, with 3 fields, or is there any other way, and better than `any`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `NgbDateStruct` in the ng-bootstrap library :

`import { NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`

Copied from `ng-bootstrap` typing file :

```
/**
 * Interface of the model of the NgbDatepicker and NgbInputDatepicker directives
 */
export interface NgbDateStruct {
    /**
     * The year, for example 2016
     */
    year: number;
    /**
     * The month, for example 1=Jan ... 12=Dec
     */
    month: number;
    /**
     * The day of month, starting at 1
     */
    day: number;
}
```